# -[NSConcreteMutableData _isResizable]: issue with UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimage

I am getting the error below:

```
 -[NSConcreteData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9954d30
```

on this code:

```
UIImage *cachedImage = [self cachedImageForUrl:self.imageSource];
if (cachedImage) {
    self.image = cachedImage;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: please make sure image and cachedImage are both of UIImage type and not of NSData. Also, check if they are not going out of scope.

Comment: yes it should be a UIImage, as I revised the code above.. any other idea?

Comment: ok do one thing (I assume that self.image is reference to UIImage obejct). use if (cachedImage && [cachedImage isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){//your code..}.. this will check whether the supplied object cachedImage is UIimage type or not. The problem that log shows is that we are assiging some NSData object to image type and it is trying to do some image operation on it.

Comment: Try running with zombies enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ARC? If not, this can happen when `self.image` doesn't correctly retain the cachedImage. When cachedImage gets dealloc'ed and self tries to access it, that memory might now point to random other classes (like NSConcreteData). How did you define the `@property` for UIImage *image?